# How to detect if Javascript/JQuery object has a height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through a DOM to change the display characteristics of different elements. I loop through the elements, and use the JQuery .height() method to get a height:

```
var myHeight = myJQueryElement.height();
```

Trouble is, when I hit a "comment" element in Firefox, I get this error:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js ::  :: line 18"  data: no]

Ok, fine, I can check the nodeType, right? No, oddly, when I call:

```
var nt = myJQueryElement.nodeType;
```

the nodeType is always "undefined". Weird, because when I click on the element in the Javascript debugger in Firebug, it show me a correct nodeType of 8.

All I want to do is check whether the element has a height > 0, and skip it otherwise.

Any clues how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the DOM node, not the jQuery object.

```
 // ----------------------v----extract the DOM node at index 0
var nt = myJQueryElement[ 0 ].nodeType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate your error when iterating the `<body>` like so:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

for (var i in body.children) {
    console.log(body.children[i]);
    console.log($(body.children[i]).nodeType);
}
```

But I don't get the error when iterating with `.each()`

```
$('body').children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).height());
});
```

maybe use `.each()` with recursion to iterate through the DOM elements